# In SQLAlchemy-migrate, what's the point of using "test"?

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlalchemy

Why use `py manage.py test` ?

What's the point? It creates the table anyway... if I wanted to test it, then I wouldn't want it to create the actual table!!!

Comment: afaik, the test does an up- and downgrade to test if your script throws any errors. it's basically the same as running upgrade and downgrade to current version manually, I didn't find any other benefits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test is meant to perform both the upgrade and the downgrade steps. You want to verify that the application is usable in both states. So the idea would be to upgrade, run tests, downgrade, run tests, and verify you don't break things.

If the test run fails, it gives you a chance to clean it up, reset, and try again. Usually, I'd say that the test run must completely cleanly before the migration is considered "good" and able to be committed to the code base.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. What if during test, a table is created, but then fails at a step after that table is created, resulting in an error? manage.py then exists, and the table is still in the database (not dropped)

Comment: Yes, but you're developing the migration in a dev environment right? It's up to you to manually clean up the mess that your migration has made and try again. The goal is to keep working on what your migration does until it runs and de-runs cleanly. Now it's safe to officially use.